# How to implement application level pagination over ScalarDB

Tags: scalardb

This question is part-Cassandra and part ScalarDB. I am using ScalarDB which provide ACID support on top of `Cassandra`. The library seem to be working well! Unfortunately, ScalarDB doesn't support pagination though so I have to implement it in the application.

Consider this scenario in which `P` is primary key, `C` is clustering key and `E` is other data within the partition

```
Partition => { P,C1,E1
P,C2,E1
P,C2,E2
P,C2,E3
P,C2,E4
P,C3,E1
...
P,Cm,En
}
```

In ScalarDB, I can specify start and end values of keys so I suppose ScalarDB will get data only from the specified rows. I can also limit the no. of entries fetched.

https://scalar-labs.github.io/scalardb/javadoc/com/scalar/db/api/Scan.html

Say I want to get entries `E3` and `E4` from `P,C2`. For smaller values, I can specify start and end clustering keys as C2 and set fetch limit to say 4 and ignore `E1` and `E2`. But if there are several hundred records then this method will not scale.

For example say `P,C1` has 10 records, `P,C2` has 100 records and I want to implement pagination of 20 records per query. Then to implement this, I'll have to
Query 1 – Scan – primary key will be P, clustering start will be C1, clustering end will be Cn as I don’t know how many records are there.

- get `P,C1`. This will give 10 records
- get `P,C2`. This will give me 20 records. I'll ignore last 10 and combine `P,C1`'s 10 with `P,C2`'s first 10 and return the result.

I'll also have to maintain that the last cluster key queried was `C2` and also that 10 records were fetched from it.

Query 2 (for next pagination request) - Scan – primary key will be P, clustering start will be C2, clustering end will be Cn as I don’t know how many records are there.
Now I'll fetch `P,C2` and get 20, ignore 1st 10 (as they were sent last time), take the remaining 10, do another fetch using same Scan and take first 10 from that.

Is this how it should be done or is there a better way? My concern with above implementation is that every time I'll have to fetch loads of records and dump them. For example, say I want to get records 70-90 from `P,C2` then I'll  still query up to record 60 and dump the result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary keys and Clustering keys compose a primary key so your above example looks not right.
Let' assume the following data structure.

```
P, C1, ...
P, C2, ...
P, C3, ...
...
```

Anyways, I think one of the ways could be as follows. Assuming the page size is 2.

1. Scan with start (P, C1) inclusive, ascending and with limit 2. Results stored in R1
2. Get the last record of R1 -> (P, C2).
3. Scan with start the previous last record (P, C2) not inclusive, ascending with limit 2.
   ...

Comment: The issue I am seeing now is that I'll have to maintain record of all primary and clustering keys. Does ScalarDB provide a way to get meta data (like what primary and clustering keys a table has)?